# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException Play Console Error

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting the following crash log in Play Console, but I'm unable to find the line which is causing it.
The error I'm getting is below

**com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException**

*com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot*

Type:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException
```

Logs:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean (CustomClassMapper.java:56)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass (CustomClassMapper.java:81)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass (CustomClassMapper.java)
at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue (DataSnapshot.java:10)
at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot (ClassSnapshotParser.java:2)
at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot (ClassSnapshotParser.java:2)
at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot (BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:14)
at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get (BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:6)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem (FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:2)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder (FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.java)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder (RecyclerView.java:29)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:39)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:498)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:5)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:1)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next (LinearLayoutManager.java:11)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk (LinearLayoutManager.java)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill (LinearLayoutManager.java:38)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren (LinearLayoutManager.java:356)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2 (RecyclerView.java:38)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure (RecyclerView.java:65)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26415)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7845)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26415)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal (RelativeLayout.java:735)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure (RelativeLayout.java:481)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26415)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal (RelativeLayout.java:735)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure (RelativeLayout.java:481)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26415)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal (RelativeLayout.java:735)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure (RelativeLayout.java:481)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26415)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7845)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:154)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26415)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7845)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26415)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7845)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26415)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7845)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26415)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7845)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure (DecorView.java:1013)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26415)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:2352)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2204)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:9003)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:996)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:794)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:729)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:981)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7948)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Could someone please help me understand what is causing this error and how can I resolve this?

---

This is the model class I'm using

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@Keep

public class Messenger_Model {

String sentTime;

public Messenger_Model(){

}

public Messenger_Model(

        String sentTime

) {
    this.sentTime = sentTime;
}

public String getSentTime() {
    return sentTime;
}

public void setSentTime(String sentTime) {
    this.sentTime = sentTime;
}
}
```

And this is the DB structure

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is that your model class and data storing code in firebase db is not mismatch.
To make more conclusions need more information about your data structures.

Comment: I've added model class and DB structure

Comment: I've many modal classes in different activities. How will I know which one is causing this error?

Comment: Can you show the code where you initialised FirebaseRecyclerAdapter? And please expand the firebase db tree to see the child structures